# .htaccess rewrite to ssl with browser language detection and subdomain removal

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, language-detection

I'm trying to rewrite any request to my ssl domain:

https://domain.com/

I got that working with the following rules:

```
# Remove any subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com [R=301,L]

# Force ssl connection
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

In addition I want to detect the browser language and if detected I want the redirect to the detected language but the first rule (remove subdomain and rewrite to ssl) should still match.

I've tried something like this to detect the browser language:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.domain.com [NC]         
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$         
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$         
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/de/ [L,R=301]
```

How can I get this to work (at best with one redirect only)?